# How do I check a value prior to setting it in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, getter-setter

I have a simple property on an Ember object that I want to run some value checks on before actually setting and triggering/canceling the change. I'm not having much luck finding any code samples or info on this. The pattern I'm used to from other frameworks is to do it within the setter - something like:

Within an Ember Object

```
propertyName : function(key, value) {
    // Setter
    if (arguments !== 1) {
        if (setCheckHere) {
           return this._super(key, value); // ??  is this right?
        } 
        // ?? if ignoring what should I return instead?
    }
}.property()
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what methods I should be calling and what needs to be returned.

Comment: your question is ok, but the title isn't. "what is the best way to..." usually falls into "not constructive" because "..likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.", so you might want to change it

Comment: Patterns for working Ember are evolving. But okay - done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My proposal would be the following, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/NUTAz/:

```js
Ember.Object.create({
    _foo: undefined,
    foo: function(key, value) {
        // david
        if (arguments.length === 1) {
            return this._foo;
        }

        // setter
        if (value === 42) {
            // set the value because it's cool
            this._foo = value;
        }

        // allow chaining, so this.set('foo', 12).set('name', 'Fünke');
        return this;
    }.property()
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

A even better solution would be to use a closure as @mraken suggests, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/Zacfh/:

```
Ember.Object.create({
    foo: (function() {
        var _foo;
        return function(key, value) {
            // david
            if (arguments.length === 1) {
                return _foo;
            }

            // setter
            if (value === 42) {
                _foo = value;
            }

            return this;
        }.property();
    })()
});
```

Comment: How about encapsulating _foo inside a self-executing closure on foo : (function(){ var _foo; return function(key, value) { ... }})()

Comment: You can use the third argument in the function which is cached value.  https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/tests/computed_test.js#L241